# How to concat two Strings by each character by using java8 stream API?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need help on solving this problem,I have two Strings

```
String s1 = "Mohan";
String s2 = "1234567";
```

I need output as

```
"M1o2h3a4n567"
```

like s1 first character then s2 first character.

How can I solve this using java8 stream API?

I converted two strings to a list then in stream API tried to use reduce but I know this is not the right solution.

Comment: @haba713 it not giving the expected output .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly.
`String result = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length())).mapToObj(i -> (i < s1.length() ? s1.charAt(i) + "" : "") + (i < s2.length() ? s2.charAt(i) + "" : "")).collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a whole lot of options, each one with advantages and disadvantages.

Here's another way, using an `IntStream` and a `StringBuilder`:

```java
String result = IntStream.range(0, Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length()))
    .collect(
            StringBuilder::new,
            (sb, i) -> {
                if (i < s1.length()) {
                    sb.append(s1.charAt(i));
                }
                if (i < s2.length()) {
                    sb.append(s2.charAt(i));
                }
            },
            StringBuilder::append
    )
    .toString();
```

What happens here is that we loop (using an `IntStream`) over all indexes of the largest of both strings (using `max(s1.length(), s2.length())`).

Then we collect into a `StringBuilder`, adding the character from `s1` if it exists, and then the same for `s2`.

Note that this code doesn't use any intermediate substrings.

However, I think an ol' skool for or foreach loop is just as good as using streams.